# The true way: UI.registerHelper or Template.registerHelper?

Tags: meteor

I dont know, why two different methods is available.

[UI.registerHelper](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/spacebars-secrets-exploring-meteor-new-templating-engine/)

[Template.registerHelper](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`UI` was deprecated as part of [0.9.1](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#v091). The name change is currently backward compatable, however you should start using `Template.registerHelper` going forward.